# How to GET to LinkedIn API?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, axios, linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve user info from LinkedIn API, calling `api.linkedin.com/me` and sending token within axios. But I am getting 404 error - https://gyazo.com/b08b3eba1cbfd5809ede994b1af67fb5

I am able to get an access token from their API, but I stuck on getting user info

Here is a piece after I get a token I call `api.linkedin.com/me` like:

```
.then(function (response) {
    axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/me', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      })
  })
  .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
  }
```

I need to be able to fetch data of the user, but I cannot make a valid request

Thank you in advance!

Comment: wha do you see in `console.log` ?

Comment: Consider posting the whole `fetch` request, and console logging each response.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `get` URL to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` should solve the problem.

I say this because `https://api.linkedin.com/me` redirects to a 404 page on linkedin, however, `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` returns a `json` response.

Comment: Yes, but I ended up with - https://gyazo.com/2831e19a603273cd9b6576cb2f07f542 error, can't get what's wrong

Comment: Can you check if you are even receiving an auth token?

Comment: [This](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/error-handling#error_codes) has the exact error as an example.